# Docker Getting Started: failed to fetch oauth token - Certificate issue

Tags: docker

I am getting started with Docker and following the instructions on the Microsoft Getting Started page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/docker/tutorials/docker-tutorial

In the "Build a container image for the app" I am executing the following:

```
docker build --pull --rm -f "app/Dockerfile" -t getting-started "app"
```

And am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: node:20-alpine: failed to authorize: 
failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": 
tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have also tried a different example from another site and end up in the same bad place.

This is on Windows/VS Code/WSL2.  My gut is telling me it is something basic but I don't see other cases like this on Google.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to execute `docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started` successfully? or you get the same error?

Comment: That was successful. ty

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. My understanding is that since Docker Desktop was installed on Windows, the Docker certificates needed to be separately installed on WSL2/Ubuntu.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Ran the following lines in WSL2:

```
# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```